# How to use a Judy array

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am interested in Judy Arrays and try to use it. But i had unable to do any useful thing using it. Every time it gives me casting errors.. Sample c++ code and the error given below.

```cpp
#include "Judy.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int      Rc_int;                           // return code - integer
    Word_t   Rc_word;                          // return code - unsigned word
    Word_t   Index = 12, Index1 = 34, Index2 = 55, Nth;
    Word_t  PValue;                            // pointer to return value
    //Pvoid_t PJLArray = NULL;                 // initialize JudyL array


    Pvoid_t JudyArray = NULL;
    char      String[100];

    PWord_t _PValue;
    JSLI( JudyArray, _PValue, (uint8_t *) String);  

    return(0);

} // main()
```

This gives me the error

```
m.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
m.cpp:19: error: invalid conversion from â€˜long unsigned int**â€™ to â€˜void**â€™
m.cpp:19: error:   initializing argument 1 of â€˜void** JudySLIns(void**, const uint8_t*, J_UDY_ERROR_STRUCT*)â€™
```

Please anyone help me to figure out what is the error what i'm doing..
Thanks

Comment: In C++, why not use `std::vector` and `std::basic_string` instead?

Comment: @Billy: I have given a research to conclude a data structure which can optimize the performance of a on memory data structure. Thats why im trying to learn about Judy

Comment: `std::vector` already does the kind of automatic resizing that Judy claims to do.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It claims to do more than automatically resize. It claims that it can efficiently represent sparse arrays, which `::std::vector` cannot do. It would be interesting to write an STL compliant wrapper around the Judy Array library.

Comment: ive read that Judy arrays are particularly good on sequential or near sequential access, but not very good on random access ( http://www.nothings.org/computer/judy/ http://rusty.ozlabs.org/?p=153 ). When i say good - i actually mean in comparison to a decent hash implementation. so depending on your use case, you might not see any performance gain over one of the many C++ compatible hash library options out there, for instance http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/ . dont take this as a recommendation against judy, just as suggestion to make sure you checked multiple sources of info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/JudySL_3x.htm), you have the `_PValue` and `JudyArray` parameters reversed. Make your call look like this:

```
JSLI( _PValue, JudyArray, (uint8_t *) String);
```

Also, try not compiling it as C++ code. So far, your test uses no C++ features. I bet it will compile as C code. It looks like JudyArray relies on the fact that C will do certain kinds of implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types.

If this is the case, I'm not sure what to do about it. The error messages you're getting tell me that `JSLI` is a macro. In order to fix the error message you have in the comments on this answer, you'd have to reach inside the macro and add a typecast.

These kinds of implicit conversions are allowed in C because otherwise using `malloc` would always require ugly casts. C++ purposely disallows them because the semantics of `new` make the requirement that the result of `malloc` be cast to the correct type unimportant.

I don't think this library can be used effectively in C++ for this reason.

Comment: Ive done it.. But it also gives me an error. `m.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
m.cpp:19: error: invalid conversion from â€˜void*â€™ to â€˜long unsigned int*â€™`

Comment: @DarRay: Interesting! I've updated my answer. I'm not at all sure you can use this library in C++.

Comment: I have went down and replaced macros and used direct function         `JudySLIns(  (void **) (&(_PValue)),  (uint8_t *) String,  ((PJError_t) NULL)  );` and got the following linking error `gcc m.cpp
/tmp/ccEOpf60.o: In function 'main':
m.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to 'JudySLIns'
/tmp/ccEOpf60.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @DarRay: Try it with a C compiler. If it works, I'm not willing to help you make a library that's designed to be C only work in C++ unless you expend significant effort on the project yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, you pass JudySLIns(void**, const uint8_t*, J_UDY_ERROR_STRUCT*) a wrong parameter, the first one, you'b better check it!

Answer (score 0):

For integer keys there is a C++ wrapper at http://judyhash.sourceforge.net/